# MySQL self join performance: fact or just bad indexing?

Tags: mysql, performance, join, indexing, entity-attribute-value

As an example: I'm having a database to detect visitor (bots, etc) and since not every visitor have the same amount of 'credential' I made a 'dynamic' table like so: see fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ca4c8/1 (simplified version).

This returns me the profile ID that I use to gather info about each profile (in another DB). Depending on the profile type I query the table with different `name`clause (name='something') (ei: hostname, ipAddr, userAgent, HumanId, etc).

I'm not an expert in SQL but I'm familiar with indexes, constraints, primary, unique, foreign key etc. And from what I saw from these search results:

- [Mysql Self-Join Performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9089994/mysql-self-join-performance)
- [How to tune self-join table in mysql like this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16553536/how-to-tune-self-join-table-in-mysql-like-this)
- [Optimize MySQL self join query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927356/optimize-mysql-self-join-query)
- [JOIN Performance Issue MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13277127/join-performance-issue-mysql)
- [MySQL JOIN performance issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984125/mysql-join-performance-issue)

Most of them have **comments** about bad performance on self-join but **answers** tend to go for the **missing index** cause.

So the final question is: is self joining a table makes it more prone to bad performance assuming that everything is indexed properly?

---

On a side note, more information about the table: might be irrelevant to the question but is well in context for my particular situation:

- column flag is used to mark records for deletion as the user I use from php don't have DELETE permission over this database. Sorry, Security is more important than performance
- I added the 'type' that will go with info I get from the user agent. (ie: if anything is (at least seems to be) a bot, we will only search for type 5000.
- Column 'name' is unfortunately a varchar indexed in the primary key (with profile and type).
- I tried to use as much INT and filtering (WHERE) in the SELECT query to reduce eventual lost of performance (if that even matters)
- I'm willing to study and tweak the thing if needed unless someone with a high background in mysql tells me it's really not a good thing to do.

This is a big project I have in development so I cannot test it with millions of records for now but I wonder if performance will be an issues as this grows. Any input, links, references, documentation or test procedure (maybe in comments) will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A self-join is no different than joining two different tables.  The optimizer will pick one 'table', usually based on the `WHERE`, then do a Nested Loop Join into the other.  In your case, you have implied, via `LEFT`, that it should work only one way.  (The Optimizer will ignore that *if* it sees no need for it.

Your keys are find for that Fiddle.

The real problem is "Entity-Attribute-Value", which is a messy way to lay out data in tables.  Your query seems to be saying "find a (limit 1) `profile` (entity) that has a certain pair of attributes (name = Googlebot `AND` addr = ...).

It would be so much easier, and faster, to have two columns (name and addr) and a "composite" `INDEX(name, addr)`.

I recommend doing that for the *common* "attributes", then put the rest into a single column with a JSON string.  See [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/eav).

Comment: thanks you for the documentation, the kind of input i was looking for. The reason i didn't use two colums is that different type of profiles need different amount of attributes. (ei: apis needs 4 : name, addr, appid, token).

Comment: "A self-join is no different than joining two different tables." seems like a straight forward answers and looking at your profile i feel the urge to tag this as solved.